# iPhone SDK: how to switch to previous view when video playback is over?

Tags: iphone, video, view

There is an application which uses several view controllers. In one of them there is a button which switches to a new view, and there, in viewDidLoad method, I launch a video playback. But when it's stopped, an empty view pops up instead of the previous view I'm working with.

What is a proper way to switch back to the previous view automatically? I've read about MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification so I can use it.

It's a navigation-based application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification you just pop the current view controller with the popViewController... messages:

```
[yourViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

the navigationController property contains the active navigation controller.

see [Apple docs for UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationController)